# Clion debug session: breakpoints domiciliation in /proc/self/cwd

Tags: debugging, clion

I am running Clion IDE on linux (rh6), version 2019.3.2.

Breakpoints that I set in my project source files (e.g. /path/to/myproject/myFile.cpp) are ignored when running the debug session - they go from the red dot to the greyed out 'disabled' symbol when I run the debug session.

I realized (by using the 'break on exception' feature) that during the debug session the source files are seen from /proc/self/cwd/ and breakpoints are associated with that location instead of the original file, such that I end up with two tabs in the editor referencing the same source file.
Breakpoints I set in /proc/self/cwd/myFile.cpp are hit.

How does Clion come up with that source duplication? Does anyone know a way around that?

Note that I am building outside of the IDE and using a CMakeLists.txt purely as a project file (to get navigation/include resolution). I have an add_custom_target() statement to be able to create a debug target.

My CMakeLists.txt (simplified so it's intelligible):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(MyProject)

set(SOURCE_FILES
        Source1.C
        Source1.H
        Source2.C #has a main method
        Source2.H
)

add_library(libMyProject STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES}) # that's so the source files are visible by Clion (to get syntax highlighting etc)
add_custom_target(myProject_exe) # The executable I am trying to debug. I am building using bazel from outside Clion so I need to make the IDE aware of that custom target
```

Comment: 1. `/proc/` is a virtual file system, the files stay where they were. 2. Please provide your `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for checking on that - I added the gist of my CMakeLists.txt. Would you know why Clion resorts to a virtual file system in that instance or in general?

Comment: Hm, I missed the external build part on the first read. I wonder if you are debugging `libMyProject` or  `myProject_exe `. I expect that `libMyProject` needs to be the debug configuration target to pick up any breakpoints at all. If it's not the case, then your best bet is CLion support or issue tracker.

Comment: Or check out a compilation database projects in CLion.